# journal rotate data loss

Tags: kubernetes, journal

I am writing a log from kubernetes to journal.
If I run `for(; n <50000;)` on a specific POD,
Only about 20000 logs have been written.
It seems to be lost when doing logrotate.
Is there any document explaining how logrotate works?

Logging does not change the file size of the `/var/log/journal` path.
Where is the log written?

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html

Comment: I have already seen the document.
It seems to be stored in `/var/log/journal/*/system.journal`.
But `tail -f /var/log/journal/*/system.journal` does not change.

Comment: If i look at the `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT = docker.service`, i see the missing part in the middle of my log.